# Is there a function to clean up comments in kickstarter.com?

Tags: kickstarter

A lot of project pages on kickstarter.com are messed up with nonsense comments ("noise" in SE terms). Is there a function for project maintainers to clean those up or does one who wants to provide and maintain a readable comment section have to disable comments (possible?) and provide such at a different location?

Search engine (google.de, yahoo.com) results are not useful because mostly related to projects containing keywords.